# Tango finding walls, or recognizing angle of wall

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, tango

I need to recognize wall by using tango sdk and place there any AR wall (I can`t find angle of wall). I have searched a lot, but couldn`t find anything helpful. [here is a link with same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234011/how-to-detect-floor-and-other-surfaces-in-google-tango), but there is no any normal answer.

please any help will be appretiated I have stucked already week at it, I have tried changing files of tangopointcloud, but ther is no any helpful thing.

Comment: The answer you posted is pretty detailed. There's no 1-liner function for finding a wall from Tango.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect floor and other surfaces in Google Tango?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234011/how-to-detect-floor-and-other-surfaces-in-google-tango)